# Appropriate way for learning about career path?

Tags: career-development, job-offer, human-resources

What is the proper way of asking HR about the career path/development opportunities regarding a position you've been offered?

Here's how I'm thinking of wording my question:

```
Hi XXX,

Could you please tell me more about the career path? What sort of trajectory
is normally for this position and opportunities I can have for personal
development?
```

For my particular case, it's at a tech company but it would great to hear from others the best ways of inquiring about non-technical aspects such as this.

Answer (score 2):

The template email you have written is a good place to start. You can also ask the same of your hiring manager. Talk to current employees. For entry level interviews, you will usually get a lunch buddy. Generally your lunch buddy is not a part of the hiring process and a good opportunity to ask more candid questions about career advancement. Talk to former employees as well, if you know any, or look through reviews on [Glassdoor](https://www.glassdoor.com/index.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Find out if HR dept has a website (internal/extrenal) and you may find that the process is explained there.

Good luck!